# Adding data from localStorage to cookie with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to add the data from `localStorage` to the cookie.

Here is the code:

```
let cookie_name = "points_trigger";
let cookie_data = localStorage.getItem('content');
document.cookie = `${cookie_name}=${cookie_data[0].outerHTML}`;
```

The data from `localStorage` is an `HTML` code.

This code creates a cookie but the content is `undefined`. And also, I don't have any errors in the console.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-a-cookie-with-jquery

Comment: Please also provide an example of `cookie_data`. `let cookie_data = localStorage.getItem('content'); console.log(cookie_data);`

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` can only store strings.

So `cookie_data` will be a string …

(maybe `"[object HTMLDivElement]"` if you're trying to store an HTML element in there)

… which means that `cookie_data[0]` will be the first character of that string …

(`"["`)

… and `outerHTML` will be `undefined` because strings don't have `outerHTML` properties.

You need to serialise the data you are storing in localStorage to a string, and then parse it on the way out.

Comment: Can you maybe give me some example since I'm not so good with JS?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
document.cookie = "points_trigger=" + localStorage.getItem('content');
```

This assumes that `localStorage.getItem('content')` contains all the neccesary details for the cookie. For example, if it contained `"John Smith"`, the resulting code would do something like:

```
document.cookie = "points_trigger=John Smith";
```

See More: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp